# Decimal to binary, prints wrong answers

Tags: java, binary, stack, decimal

Hey i was wondering if anyone can find a problem with my code? If you can could you explain it to me please! When i input 99 i get 1100 011 when it should be 0110 0011.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SchoolHomework {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Program that converts decimal to binary!");
    int dec;
    System.out.println("Please type in a decimal number:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<Integer> todec = new Stack<Integer>();
    dec = input.nextInt();
    if (dec < 0){
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a positive number!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while (dec != 0){
        int stackv = dec % 2;
        todec.push(stackv);
        dec /= 2;

    }
    System.out.println(dec + " To binary is: ");
    int counter = 0;
    while (!(todec.isEmpty() )) {
        String val = todec.pop().toString();
        System.out.print(val);
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter >= 4){
            counter = 0;
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to pad the result with leading zeros to 4, 8, 12 etc digits.

Comment: Are you able to explain that, sorry im not very advanced

Comment: You result is correct (mathematically speaking). But if you have only seven digits, you want to put another `0` in front, so that you have eight digits, and it will print nicely.

Comment: So what do i add, should i put a counter++; after the if statement or what?

Comment: Count the size of your stack (or ask it, if that is permissible). Then push enough zeros onto the stack to reach the next multiple of four.

Comment: So, int sizeOfStack=todec.size();, but then i get lost im not really sure what to do.

Comment: Hey JimBob101 look at my solution, hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you wrote looks very good. You were near the solution. The easy one is to continue to push zeroes to your stack until you reach a length multiple of 4. Let me know if you got a good note ;)

```
import java.util.*;
public class SchoolHomework {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program that converts decimal to binary!");
        int dec;
        System.out.println("Please type in a decimal number:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<Integer> todec = new Stack<Integer>();
        dec = input.nextInt();
        if (dec < 0){
            System.out.println("Error: Please enter a positive number!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int size = 0;

        while (dec != 0){
            int stackv = dec % 2;
            todec.push(stackv);
            dec /= 2;
            size++;
        }
        if (size % 4 > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 4 - (size % 4); i++) {
               todec.push(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dec + " To binary is: ");
        int counter = 0;
        while (!(todec.isEmpty() )) {
            String val = todec.pop().toString();
            System.out.print(val);
            counter = counter + 1;
            if (counter >= 4){
                counter = 0;
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are inserting spaces left to right while printing. If you want to achieve the desired output then I would suggest you to start inserting spaces also into the Stack.

Here is the quick code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Program that converts decimal to binary!");
    System.out.println("Please type in a decimal number:");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<Character> todec = new Stack<Character>();
    int dec = input.nextInt();
    if (dec < 0){
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a positive number!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println(dec + " To binary is: ");
    while (dec > 0){
        int stackv = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        todec.push((char)(stackv + '0'));

        counter++;
        if (counter%4 == 0){
            todec.push(' ');
        }
    }

    /* Pad Extra Zeors */
    while (counter%4 != 0){
        counter++;
        todec.push('0');
    }

    /* Print Stack Values */
    while (!(todec.isEmpty() )) {
        String val = todec.pop().toString();
        System.out.print(val);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0110 0011
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when the last values to push to the `Stack` are `0` (could be 1 or more) and the `Stack` ends with less than 8 entries. The condition `dec != 0` is met and the loop ends. You can use `for` loop instead to ensure the stack will have 8 entries

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i)
{
    int stackv = dec % 2;
    todec.Push(stackv);
    dec /= 2;
}
```